# scanf in a loop till carriage return

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, scanf

I am trying to read user input with multiple fields. But the number of fields is not specified. I want to read all the words till the carriage return. i tried this code but it isnt working:

```
char str[256];
while(1)
{
    scanf("%s", str);
    if(str[strlen(str)] == '\n')
         break;
    else
         printf("Got %s\n", str);

}
```

Examples of user input:
1. store file1
I need to parse store and file1 and break out of the loop.
2. store file1 file2
I need to parse store, file1 and file2 and break out of the loop.

Wondering how to break out of the loop at the carriage return.

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
char str[256]
scanf("%255[^\n]", str); /*edit*/
```

which will read to a newline or (Edit:) 255 characters, whichever comes first.

Comment: I didnt know scanf works with regular expressions. if possible could you post few pointers to learn about them.

Comment: @user640639 Check out this [page](http://content.hccfl.edu/pollock/CPlus/PrintfRef.htm#scanfFormat).  It's not quite as flexible as RegEx, but it's still very powerful.

Comment: @user640639 see the edit as elbekay corrected below.  Apologies.

Comment: @jonsca What about `\r\n` delimited lines?

Answer (score 1):

You could read using fgets() then split the buffer using strtok() into tokens

that way you have full control of everything.

Comment: `fgets()` will leave the `'\n'` in the string if there's room, so the OP will have to swap that out for a `'\0'` if he/she wants everything up *until* the `'\n'`

Comment: thanks. yes i could use fgets. but i am wondering how to do it with scanf.

Comment: @user640639 my answer uses a format specifier to get a safer fgets-type effect of obeying the buffer size.  There's no reason not to use fgets itself, though.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, your char array str[256] is filled with nothing or junk, so when you do a look up, you won't find it.

Comment: I printed out strlen(str). It returns as many characters in the word being parsed. So it is not 256.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
char str[256];
while(1)
{
    scanf("%s", str);
    printf("Got %s\n",str);
    if(fgetc(stdin) == '\n')
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char str[256]
scanf("%256[^\n]", str);
```

Be careful with that code. It will overflow the char array for long strings. You want %255 in the scanf to accommodate the null terminator.

Comment: Thank you.  I was trying to protect the OP from that very thing, and I had a quintessential "brain fart."